# Sending images or buttons on facebook messenger via ibm watson configuered via botkit

Tags: facebook-messenger, watson-conversation, watson

I have made a wotson chat bot, deployed on facebbok messenger the broker is a node app just like in [this github example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware). I'm recieving text responses perfectly but how do I configure the bot to send images or buttons to the fb messenger. I have tried Respond with JSON option in watson dialog.
JSON:

```
{
  "output": {

  },
"context":{
"facebook":{
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
        "type":"image",
        "payload":{
            "url":"https://petersapparel.com/img/shirt.png"
        }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

I Think there is some problem with my JSON.

Answer (score 1):

To send buttons define message with `template_type` **generic** and buttons with `type` **postback**

```
controller.hears('test', 'message_received', function(bot, message) {

    var attachment = {
        'type':'template',
        'payload':{
            'template_type':'generic',
            'elements':[
                {
                    'title':'Chocolate Cookie',
                    'image_url':'http://cookies.com/cookie.png',
                    'subtitle':'A delicious chocolate cookie',
                    'buttons':[
                        {
                        'type':'postback',
                        'title':'Eat Cookie',
                        'payload':'chocolate'
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    };

    bot.reply(message, {
        attachment: attachment,
    });

});
```

To send attachment define attachment message with resource url and call upload method.

```
controller.hears('test', 'message_received', function(bot, message) {

var attachment = {
        "type":"image",
        "payload":{
            "url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/803642201653858305/IAW1DBPw_400x400.png",
            "is_reusable": true
        }
    };

    controller.api.attachment_upload.upload(attachment, function (err, attachmentId) {
        if(err) {
            // Error
        } else {
            var image = {
                "attachment":{
                    "type":"image",
                    "payload": {
                        "attachment_id": attachmentId
                    }
                }
            };
            bot.reply(message, image);
        }
    });
}
```

Check [Botkit Messenger documentation](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/docs/readme-facebook.md).

Comment: Is there a way to do it from watson dilog response? Not from the broker app

Comment: you typically decide on what to respond in your broker app not from the Watson dialog. Watson dialog response is all about natural language processing i.e. detecting what intent does a users statement is all about. based on that you decide what you want to do. For some simple intent - yes you can configure the dialog response. but scenarios like yours - its best in broker.